# Safely conditionally setting secrets in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

Say I have a repository_dispatch workflow where the payload has a variable called `env` that can have either "production" or "test" values. In the repo I have secrets called `CREDS` and `TEST_CREDS`. Depending on the value of `env` I'd like to set the value of `CREDS`. I have an example below. My question is, is this a safe way of doing this or can anyone recommend a good way of conditionally setting the secrets?

```
name: perform-task

on:
  repository_dispatch:
     types: [task]

env:
  CREDS: ${{ secrets.CREDS }}
  TEST_CREDS : ${{ secrets.TEST_CREDS }}
  ## payload vars
  ENV: ${{ github.event.client_payload.env }}

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:   
      - name: Set CREDS 
        run: |
          if [[ "$ENV" == "test" ]]; then
            echo "CREDS=$TEST_CREDS" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "CREDS=$CREDS" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
      
      - name: Configure Credentials
        with:
          creds-to-use: ${{ env.CREDS }}
```

Comment: You could minimize scope of creds to that step only. However, if `ENV` represents the `environment` then why aren't you configuring those creds in their respective environment?

Comment: I see. So what you are saying is have two steps with an `if` and then apply the creds at the right level.

Comment: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment.